# Can I use ext4 on my SD card on a non-rooted android 5.1.1 (lollipop)?

Tags: external-sd, 5.1-lollipop, file-system

I'd like to use ext4 on my SD card, or anything besides fat32 really. Something which supports files > 4GB in size.

Unfortunately, unlike it [apparently was back in the day](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/4497/202988), now ext4 and even exfat-formatted SD cards are met with a message like "filesystem missing or not supported, click 'okay' to format", which when clicked, causes android to happily reinstate a fat32 filesystem.

Is there any way around this on an unrooted system?
Or am I stuck?

Comment: ... and any Storage Access Framework-degraded Android? :)